# Convert milliseconds to hh:mm:ss with JS adds 1 hour

Tags: javascript

I have a duration in milliseconds and i would like to display it with format hh:mm:ss, so i've tried to use the

```
var dtFromMillisec = new Date(myDuration);
var result = dtFromMillisec.getHours() + ":" + dtFromMillisec.getMinutes() + ":" + dtFromMillisec.getSeconds();
```

The time that i get should be for example 00:00:15 but it's 1:0:15, why do i always get 1 more hour?

Comment: Can you show your input and output? What is `myDuration`?

Comment: Working with the current date works fine so perhaps it's something with your input: http://jsfiddle.net/r7qqr85g/

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with durations, don't use a `Date` object, do it as follows:

```
var result = Math.floor(myDuration/(1000*60*60)) + ":" + Math.floor(myDuration/(1000*60))%60 + ":" + Math.floor(myDuration/1000)%60;
```

That `Date` constructor is meant to be used when you have a date that can be represented in milliseconds that have passed since the 01 January, 1970 UTC.

**Edit**

Your `Date` object is probably showing 1 hour because you are in a timezone with GMT + 1, thus the date at millisecond zero is `01 January, 1970 UTC 01:00:00`.

Comment: Well for myDuration = 9702 i get result = 0.002695:0.1617:9.702  :/

Comment: Add `Math.Round` then. For 9702 milliseconds you should get 10 seconds, which is correct.